# Why can't handle "io.UnsupportedOperation" error by try-except

Tags: python, error-handling

Running the following code will raise an io.UnsupportedOperation error, because the file is open in "write" mode -

```
with open("hi.txt", "w") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

The output is -

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

So, we can try to cover this up by doing this -

```
try:
    with open("hi.txt", "w") as f:
        print(f.read())
except io.UnsupportedOperation:
    print("Please give the file read permission")
```

Output -

```
NameError: name 'io' is not defined
```

Even removing "io." spits out the same error -

```
try:
    with open("hi.txt", "w") as f:
        print(f.read())
except UnsupportedOperation:
    print("Please give the file read permission")
```

Output -

```
NameError: name 'UnsupportedOperation' is not defined
```

Why isn't it working? Isn't "io.UnsupportedOperation" an error?

Comment: You will have to import it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The io.UnsupportedError is found in the module io. Therefore, before we can use it, we need to import io

`import io`

then when we are testing for the error in the try except clause we can use io.UnsupportedError.
This gives us:

```
import io

try:
    with open("hi.txt", "w") as f:
        print(f.read())
except io.UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)
```

or if you are only using the io module for checking this specific error.

```
from io import UnsupportedError

try:
    with open("hi.txt", "w") as f:
        print(f.read())
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)
```